# Table size issue in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a `<table>` with CSS property of `width: auto`, which has a variable number of columns. The rightmost column has no width set. In IE8/Firefox3.6.12 the table resizes as desired according to the content width of that column. `<table>`).  In IE7, it fills out to the right border of the containing .  By setting the width of that column in CSS, I was able to get it to display with the same width across IE7/IE8/Firefox3.6.12.

Comment: have you tried table-layout: fixed; ? anyway post some code of the context of the table, to know what properties has his parent.

Comment: The content of the column would be interesting too.

Comment: In IE7, it fills out to the right border of the containing .?? "By setting the width of that column in CSS" - what is the style you used?

Comment: Just to repeat what Pedro Correia has said: it would be helpful if you could give more detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood right your question but,  Did you try adding a width:auto; to THAT column in particularly???

What I would probably try If I would be working with tables in IE is to have most of the elements with a defined widht and height. Sometimes when there is no specification the elements doesnt display...

Maybe thats the problem...

If not, please add some code so we can see better your problem.

Comment: There is no issue.  I was just describing how I solved a problem.